# Allowing accent insensitive search in bootstrap table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am building a website utilising Bootstrap that uses information from a MySQL query to fill a table, in which I'd like to perform a search. I am having problems being able to search players with accented letters.

For example, I have the following scripts set up:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/table.js"></script>
            
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").DataTable({    
            pagingType: "input"
        })
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jstut.js"></script>
```

and the formation of the table is as follows:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
     <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-sm">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Player</th>
           <th>Current Team</th>
           <th>Current League</th>
           <th>Nationality</th>
           <th>Total Points</th>
           <th>Go</th>
                  
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row["Player"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["Club Transferred From"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["League Transferred From"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["First Nationality"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["TOTAL"]."</td>";
          echo "<td> <img src = \"images\search.png\" width = 13 height = 13>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }
       ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This produces the following table:

[image]

My problem is I am failing to successfully place any script here to allow me to search accent-insensitive for content. For example, searching 'Division' would not give me A. Baba's row for example, whereas 'División' would.

I've tried looking on various SO posts, including ones referring to http://jsfiddle.net/xebtyaeL/5/ with no luck at all. I wonder if this is anything to do with Bootstrap.

I am new to working with this type of code - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see you have imported `table.js`, what is that exactly? Is that a library? If so, please provide a link to it. The fiddle you mention at the bottom uses Datatables.js, but its not clear if your code does.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Wesley. The table.js file is probably redundant to be honest - it contains this with no effect to the file when removing: $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
    language: {
     paginate: {
        next: 'Next One',
        previous: 'Previous '  
         }
   } // "simple" option for 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
  });
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');


});

Comment: Which version of datatables are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9.4